# update symbology when add feature qgis

Tags: expression, qgis, auto-update, pyqgis

I'm working in QGIS and I have a virtual layer with lines geometry and categorized symbology by field "name". When I have a new name category I have to do the classify to get the new name in the list of values.

I'm looking for a way to do it automatically, that's means, when a new name category it's added to the layer, it's also automatically added in symbology. The symbol it's defined as random colors, so it can be a random line color.